# Mac wallpaper app fetching images from instagram or pinterest

Tags: osx, wallpaper, instagram, pinterest

Has anyone ever heard of a Mac app that would display wallpaper images from images stream from Instagram or Pinterest?

I would like to update my desktop background with images downloaded from some Pinterest and Instagram streams or accounts.

Does that exist?

Thanks,
T